# Dystopian book where a teen boy and girl run from labor camps; turns out they were dreaming

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read a book in middle school that I've been looking for, for years.  If I was to guess, I'd say maybe 60s-70s. I'm 34 now, so middle school would have been 1996-98.

I can't remember much of the story, but it's about a teen boy and girl running from people who wanted to put them in working fields or a labor camp, maybe. It's set in a dystopian future, I think.  While in the working fields, the people are in a dream state, where they believe they are happy, but in reality they are forced to work.

At the end of the book

> they ultimately escape, but the twist is that they are dreaming and were in the working fields (or maybe just the boy was?).

Comment: When were you in middle school?

Comment: It would help us greatly if we had a date range to go off of. We don't know if you were in middle school in the 1970s, the 2000s, or sometime in between.

Comment: I honestly don't know how old the book was. If I was to guess, I'd say maybe 60s-70s. I'm 34 now, so middle school would have been 1996-98. Thanks

Comment: Is this 'A Scanner Darkly', by Phillip K Dick?

Comment: @Liesmith: 'A Scanner Darkly' doesn't have a teen couple, but a single adult undercover cop as protagonist.

Comment: Sounds similar to another unanswered question, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175086/looking-for-a-short-story-name-and-author, if that helps at all (maybe the same story, different details?)