# 70s-80s short story: couple seemingly escaped a tyranny, but it's actually hypnosis/an illusion and they are working themselves to death as slaves

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

I am trying to find the name and author of a short story I read about 30 or 40 years ago.

The story is about a couple who tried to escape a tyrannical government.

In the end (the part I remember best), the hero meets the heroine in the fields, and they gather a harvest and take it to a community "tower of freedom" or something like that, where they roast chestnuts over a bonfire, and they believe they have escaped.

But then, in the ending, you see two regime guards talking about a nearby group of emaciated, starving group eating leaves from dry branches over a fire, and you realize they are hypnotized or some such, and they are actually dying in the fields as overworked slaves.

Comment: Just on the off-chance that it helps with identification; this reminds me of a film I saw at some point within the last few years (though likely not new at the time, the styling seemed older) on TV which seemed to follow a similar premise re: dystopia and hypnosis/illusion of surroundings. It may be that the film is based on the short-story in a Total Recall/Minority Report kinda way =)